Alternative to In-Line Editing for Goal-Setting in a List Page?
I'm designing a self-examination tool where users complete multiple questionnaires and could choose to set goals for each category and individual questionnaire. Our current index page uses a list layout that provides key information about each questionnaire.
I've been asked to add a goal-setting feature, but I’m concerned about overwhelming users if I introduce an editable dropdown field directly in the list.
Solution 1:

As a potential solution, I've considered displaying the goals as view-only in the index list and allowing users to set or edit their goals on a detailed page once they click into a specific questionnaire. However, this approach leaves me uncertain about how to handle goal-setting for categories since there is no equivalent detailed flow for them.
Solution 2:

Most UX patterns I've found focus on in-line editing within tables, but implementing such a pattern would significantly change the existing list-like layout, and I’m hesitant to take that approach.
My Question:
Are there alternative UX patterns or best practices that would allow for of goal-setting in this type of list-based UI, without overwhelming the user or drastically changing the existing layout? Any examples or suggestions for handling goal-setting at both the category and questionnaire levels would be greatly appreciated.

Are the goals a fixed amount? If yes, how many?

My suggestion will be to move the categories as tabs on top of the page if there are not too many of them.

There are 6 categories and about 20 questionnaires. and user can set a goal per questionnaire.

I would have tried this layout. Is it necessary to select the category goal level manually? From what it seems, it can be an average of all the questionnaires within.

